# Visual Studio Code Debug Error with Delve Debugger

Tags: visual-studio-code, delve

When debugging Golang on Mac machine using Visual Studio Code, or if you Upgraded your MacOS, you may see the following errors:

```
debugserver or lldb-server not found: install XCode's command line tools or lldb-server
```

or

```
could not launch process: exec: "lldb-server": executable file not found in $PATH
```

How to solve those debugging issues of vscode with delve?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Install command line developer tools by executing the following command:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Comment: I have upgraded to Venture 13.1 (22C65) and I'm getting `Can’t install the software because it is not currently available from the Software Update server.` after running `xcode-select --install`

Comment: @Marko try this: xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch

Comment: I gave in to Apple and created an AppleID and downloaded xcode from their website.